# How to show only top result for each feild group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to code up a stored procedure that will grab the top tenant for each property ID and Contract Number for the user logged in.

I have been able to get SQL to grab able to do most of it but not the bit where i only grab the top one for each group wich i need it to do.

It is a little hard to exsplain as its the first time i have had to do this. Maybe if you see the example below it will become clear of what the end result should be...

The code i am using is:

```
SELECT              Id,
                    PropertyId,
                    Name + ', ' + Address1,
                    contractNumber

FROM                PropertyTenant 

WHERE               PropertyId IN (SELECT PropertyId FROM UserProperty WHERE UserId = '5E541037-747C-43B9-BB9F-97C8728083B7')
AND                 ContractNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Results I am getting

(tenant Names and address would be diffrent in real situation but this is just dummy data i used)

```
Id  PropertyId  Tenant Name and address             contractNumber
142 1501        chris devine, 12                    1
143 1501        steven mo, 12                       1
144 1502        chris devine, 12,whitebeam close    1
145 1502        steven, 12,whitebeam close          2
146 1503        sdf adsf, asda                      1
147 1504        dddd ddds, sdsdwsd                  1
160 1532        Christopher, 1                      1
161 1532        Christopher Devine, 6               1
162 1532        Christopher Devine, 11              2
163 1532        Christopher Devine, 16              2
164 1529        Christopher Devine, 12, windy       1
165 1529        Christopher Devine, 12 dog          1
166 1523        Christopher Devine, asdfasiuuh      1
167 1523        Christopher Devine, asdasd          1
182 1538        chris devine, 12 whitebam           1
183 1538        chris devine, 12, whitebeam close   2
184 1538        chris devine, 12asd                 1
185 1561        chris devine, 12 whitebeam          1
```

The Results i would like and need, should be:

```
Id  PropertyId  Tenant Name and address             contractNumber
142 1501        chris devine, 12                    1
144 1502        chris devine, 12,whitebeam close    1
145 1502        steven, 12,whitebeam close          2
146 1503        sdf adsf, asda                      1
147 1504        dddd ddds, sdsdwsd                  1
160 1532        Christopher, 1                      1
162 1532        Christopher Devine, 11              2
164 1529        Christopher Devine, 12, windy       1
167 1523        Christopher Devine, asdasd          1
182 1538        chris devine, 12 whitebam           1
183 1538        chris devine, 12, whitebeam close   2
185 1561        chris devine, 12 whitebeam          1
```

Any help would be great thanks as i think i am going about this the totaly wrong way :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to this.

```
   with MyCTE as
(
    SELECT pt.Id
        , pt.PropertyId
        , pt.Name + ', ' + pt.Address1 as tenantinfo
        , pt.contractNumber
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY PropertyID, contractnumber order by id asc) as RowNum
    FROM PropertyTenant pt
    WHERE pt.PropertyId IN 
    (
        SELECT PropertyId 
        FROM UserProperty 
        WHERE UserId = '5E541037-747C-43B9-BB9F-97C8728083B7'
    )
    AND ContractNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
)

select *
from MyCTE
where RowNum = 1
order by id asc
```

Comment: Almost worked but i dont get contractNumber 2 to show now  on contract types 1

Comment: Yeah. didn't have any test data to work with so this was of course untested. You will need to give that column a name because it is derived. Just add "as TenantName" or whatever name you want to the cte.

Comment: Yer i did take a guess at that an got it to work so your right there but now it Almost worked but i dont get contractNumber 2 to show now only contract types 1

Comment: I assume you mean ContractNumber and not ContractType? You can add ContractType to the partition if you need that level of separation.

Comment: Thanks man you were right i got to work by doing PARTITION BY PropertyID, contractnumber order by pt.Name + ', ' + pt.Address1) as RowNum

Comment: You might want to change the ORDER BY to Id instead of Name + ',' Address1 if you are wanting the first record in the db.  Assuming Id is an identity column.

Comment: Thanks @JoshJay, your right. It did take me a while to figure it out but i did in the end. Only just seen your comment today. Just wanted to thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT          Min(Id),
                PropertyId,
                Name + ', ' + Address1,
                contractNumber

FROM  PropertyTenant 

WHERE PropertyId IN (SELECT PropertyId 
                     FROM UserProperty 
                     WHERE UserId = '5E541037-747C-43B9-BB9F-97C8728083B7')
AND ContractNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GROUP BY PropertyId, Name + ', ' + Address1, contractNumber
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry but i get same wrong results as above, thanks for trying

Comment: That isn't going to produce the desired output. The OP wants one row per PropertyID which this isn't going to do.

Comment: @SeanLange see the IDs 144, 145, 160, 162, 182, 183.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are needing the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function with a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
;with ctePropertyTenant
as
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        PropertyId,
        Name + ', ' + Address1,
        contractNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PropertyId, contractNumber ORDER BY Id) as PropertyRow
    FROM
        PropertyTenant 
    WHERE
        PropertyId IN (SELECT PropertyId FROM UserProperty WHERE UserId = '5E541037-747C-43B9-BB9F-97C8728083B7') AND
        ContractNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
)
Select
    *
from
    ctePropertyTenant
where
    PropertyRow = 1
```